# SFDX: Deployment Fails for report types with the following Error "Could not find field WhatCount in table Activity"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, custom-report-type

I have been trying to push my repository code, to my scratch org for almost 3 days now, but every time I push it using the

```
sfdx force:source:push -f -u <alias>
```

command, I get the following error,

```
Account_With_Activities | Custom Report Type | 0 | 0 | Could not find field WhatCount in table Activity
```

I have verified the metadata and in the scratch org that this field indeed exists.
Am I missing anything particular, or doing something wrong.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Please let me know If I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit this too; it seems shared activities need to be enabled in the target org and since the `allowUsersToRelateMultipleContactsToTasksAndEvents` scratch org config setting has been deprecated I think we're out of luck when it comes to automation (though you can enable it manually in Setup>Activity Settings)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_activitiessettings.htm

[Enable SharedActivities automaticaly for new scratch org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220222/enable-sharedactivities-automaticaly-for-new-scratch-org)

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015BjLQAU